# How can I access document.cookie from inside a Web Worker?

Tags: html, cookies, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

Since Web Workers can't access the `document` object, how can I access cookies in a worker script?

#### Background

I am working with Django and I need to pass the CSRF token in an AJAX post. The standard way of doing this is to get the token from `document.cookie` and pass it as a header:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', readCookie('csrftoken'));
```

([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax))

Web workers support `XMLHttpRequest` and it seems that they send the cookie to the server,  but I can't find a way to get the cookie in the script itself.

Comment: You cannot pass the cookie value when you call postMessage()?

Comment: @pd40 Yes, that is one option. The other is to render it directly when serving the worker script. I'd like to know if there is a more straightforward option that I've missed though.

Answer (score 0):

Before `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', readCookie('csrftoken'));` creates a varible to store the cookie like this:

```
ck = readCookie('csrftoken');`Removing "var" variable "ck" becomes global. This way you can access it from outside the Web Worker.`
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', ck);
```

In ck you have the cookie.